# jQuery PUT requests and browser support

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-browser

From the `jQuery.ajax` documentation for the `type` parameter:

> The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note:
>   Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used
>   here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

What specifically are they referring to when they say that PUT is not supported by all browsers? That is, are there any specific or notable examples where this is the case?